# save python output as pdf?

Tags: python, data-science, data-preprocessing, exploratory-data-analysis

I am using python notebook for the EDA and Data Science . For that I often work with the dataprep library . I want to save the report that has been created using that library into the pdf format.

Answer (score 1):

use show_browser,
in the browser you can print to pdf.
look here:

https://github.com/sfu-db/dataprep

use this:
create_report(df).show_browser()

https://docs.dataprep.ai/_downloads/1a61c6aebb3ecbe9dc9742bd6ca78ddb/titanic_dp.html